# What is this cocoon (if that is what it is)?

Tags: species-identification

I found this cocoon (or what I think looks like a cocoon) in an urban hedgerow in Upper Bavaria, Germany in early October (begin of autumn).
Around was a web, but no inhabitants were there.
Its diameter was about 3 cm and its opening showed towards the sky.

Thank you already for hints! :)

[image: cocoon seen from the side]

[image: cocoon seen from the top]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, I figured it out: it seems to be an abandoned cocoon of a [wasp spider (*Argiope bruennichi*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_bruennichi).
Images for comparison are found on [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Argiope_bruennichi) and on [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?taxon_id=50867).

Only thing that puzzles me is that usually the spiderlings overwinter in the *closed* cocoon and it was opened already in autumn (and the hedgerow is - unfortunately - neatly cut each autumn, so it is impossible the cocoon was there since the last year).
Anyway, I guess someone might have preyed on them... ¯_(ツ)_/¯